# Timepicker remove/hide default (30 mins) time interval

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datetimepicker

I want to hide or remove the default 30 min time interval from the dropdown list.

```
$(function () {
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
         // interval: 15,  <--- still showing/displaying 30 mins interval
            minHour: 0,
            maxHour: 20,
            dropdown: true,
            dynamic: false,
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('input#appt').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        interval: 60,
      //  interval: 15,  //still showing/displaying 30 mins interval
        minHour: 0,
        maxHour: 20,
        dropdown: true,
        dynamic: false,
    });
});
```